# I want to get an event for an HTML onContextMenu *after* the final selection, not at initial click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I do

```
<a href ... oncontextmenu="myFunction(event)">
```

It gets called when the user right clicks on a link, **before** the context menu appears.  But I want to get an event **after** a context menu item has been selected.  Ideally, only when they have selected "Open link in ...", so having access to what they actually clicked is desirable.

Would prefer a non-JQuery answer, but if needed, JQuery is o.k.

Added:  Explanation what I'm trying to do:

When the user directly clicks a link to another (commercial hotel finder) site, I bring up a little alert "If you book a room, please enter XXXX as the Gift Code").  Would also like to put up this alert if they right click and open the link in a new tab etc.,.,

Added#2: Thanks for the prompt and direct answers.  See my "answer" below for what I ended up doing.  I'll leave this question open in case there are other options.

Comment: Context Menus are outside the scope of your page.  You can prevent it appearing and replace it with a homemade context menu, but you cannot intercept commands the user issues via the built-in context menu.  This is a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do in Javascript, but you might be able to achieve what you are looking for by replacing the default context menu with a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The primary purpose of the `contextmenu` event is to allow a page to *replace* the browser's context menu with a menu of its own rendered as HTML. The contents of the browser's context menu are not specified by any HTML standard, and will vary from browser to browser. Most of the options in the context menu refer to actions outside the scope of the page (e.g, "copy", "view page source", "open link in new window", "save as", *etc.*), and there is no event fired on the page when they are selected unless the action being performed would normally fire an event. (For instance, selecting "Print" might fire `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint` events.)

The WHATWG HTML5 specification specifies [a `menu` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-menu-element) which can be used to add items to the browser's context menu, but [it's currently only supported under Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=menu). So that's probably not really an option either.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, and I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I would try calling the function on a set delay, like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" oncontextmenu="setTimeout(function(){alert('You called the context menu.')}, 3000);">Right-Click Me, then wait for 3 seconds.</a>
```

The only downside is that once the `alert()` is called, the context menu is hidden.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Something like this might work...  See edits to question for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I really don't think that you can show an alert box when the user opens a page in a new tab.  At least not in JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is inserting an intermediate page on my site.

Instead of directly going to the external site, the route (I'm using node & Express) brings up a intermediate page with the explanatory text, a checkbox "Got it, don't show this page again", (in my case, the answer gets stored in localStorage, others might store on the server) and a big green OK button that takes you to the external site.

If the route includes the query "?directXXX=true", (read from localStorage) you skip over the intermediate page and are immediately redirected to the external page.

This way I get a much nicer explanatory page, with an image, etc... (dialogs, even if you use something like alertify, look klunky) and I get to "intercept" **all** calls to the external site.